# Apache Camel: Route from camel tomcat servlet to cxfbean component

Tags: apache-camel

**Problem Description:**
I am failing to route from my camel servlet to a cxfbean. Route initialization fails with the following error message:

```
"Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[cxfbean:fooEndpoint] <<< in route:
 Route[[From[servlet:///?servletName=BwsServlet]] -> [To[cxfb... because of Failed to resolve 
 endpoint: cxfbean://fooEndpoint due to: null".
```

The servlet starts fine without the cxfbean.

**UPDATED**: Please note that I intend to use a [Camel Cxf Bean Component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html) as opposed to a [Camel Cxf Bean](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html).

**What I want to achieve:**
I am running a camel servlet within Tomcat. I have a bean which implements my webservice interface (generated from WSDL by CXF). I want to process the XML message bodies before passing them on to this webservice bean. I would like to use cxf bean component as opposed to a cxf endpoint bean, since I do not want to have my cxf endpoint listen on a network port in addition to the already running camel servlet.

**How my code looks like:**
My camel-config.xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="bwsRouteBuilder" class="local.com.foo.BwsRouteBuilder"/>
<bean id="fooEndpoint" class="local.com.foo.FooBws"/>
<camel:camelContext id="bws">
    <camel:routeBuilder ref="bwsRouteBuilder"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```

My route builder (written in Java DSL) looks like this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("servlet:///?servletName=BwsServlet")
    // some processing of message here
    .to("cxfbean:fooEndpoint");
}
```

**UPDATED**: Note the cxfbean URI format in the above code as defined [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html).

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BwsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BwsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

camel-cxf is included as dependency in my pom.xml.

**Where I looked at so far for help:** I was following the documentation at [Apache Camel cxfbean description](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html) and followed stackoverflow. I hope my question is not a no-brainer to answer, I am new to Camel.

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts

Comment: Could you show your `local.com.foo.FooBws` code?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a cxf bean you have to write "cxf:bean:fooEndpoint" in your route (you have forget : between cxf and bean).

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("servlet:///?servletName=BwsServlet")
    // some processing of message here
    .to("cxf:bean:fooEndpoint");
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your feedback. However, the URI format seems to be correct in my code. See [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html) for a description of the Cxf Bean Component. I updated my question accordingly.